# What is the best way to create a List<string> of column names where the column names do not exist in a string[]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a `DataTable` and I want to create a `List<string>` of the column names unless those column names are included in `string[] excludedColList`.

I know how to get a list of all column names:

```
List<string> colNamesList = (from DataColumn column in gridTable.Columns select column.ColumnName).ToList();
```

I don't know how to add the filter to exclude those listed in the `excludeColList`.

I am not sure how to ask this question so that a Google search returns applicable results, so I am trying to explain it here.

I am fine with changing `excludedColList` from a `string[]` to a `string` if it helps.

I do need it to be an exclusion list rather than an inclusion list.

**UPDATE**

As often seems to happen, as soon as I ask the question, I find an answer.  This works for me:

```
List<string> colNamesList = (from DataColumn column in gridTable.Columns select column.ColumnName).Except(excludedColList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from System.Data.DataColumn column in gridTable.Columns 
 where !excludedColList.Contains(column.ColumnName)
 select column.ColumnName).ToList()
```

or

```
(from System.Data.DataColumn column in gridTable.Columns
 select column.ColumnName).Except(excludedColList).ToList()
```

would both work